# How to send the JSON data of the Custom Matrix through API in Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript, api, matrix, powerbi

I have made a custom matrix in power bi and have an extra comment column in the last of it! The matrix will send the JSON data to server through api ***whenever I press enter after finish my comment*** [purpose is for saving all data into Database] but I have no idea to make it! Can anyone help me please?!

---

Below is HTML structure's Custom Matrix:

```
<div class="datagrid">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th colspan="undefined">Northeast</th>
                <th colspan="undefined">Southern</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>California</th>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>
                    <div contenteditable="">I'm editable</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Florida</th>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>
                    <div contenteditable="">I'm editable</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

I have converted successfully with help of @Eric Jones in this post: [How to convert Matrix HTML to JSON in Typescript (for sending through api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464685/how-to-convert-matrix-html-to-json-in-typescript-for-sending-through-api)

---

The structure of my JSON is:

```
[  
   {  
      "name_column_field":"Arizona",
      "value":"3759959.75",
      "comment":"I'm editable",
      "name_row_field":"Southern"
   },...
]
```